# xlsx convert 1 cell spanning multiple rows to have a value in each cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a xlsx in the following format:

```
Name | item | qty
Joe  |   1  |  1
     |   2  |  1
     |   3  |  2
Tim  |   2  |  1
Judy |   1  |  2
     |   4  |  1
     |   2  |  3
```

the sheet has 50k rows, is there an easy way to "fill in the blanks" so that each row contians values in each cell instead of blank cells (see both examples)? this is happening in multiple columns when ever there are multiple cells with the same value as previous.

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "fill in the blanks"? Could you clarify the issue better? Do you mean like if there is a way to auto-fill using the previous values?

Comment: Yes where ever there is a blank cell fill it in with the value instead assuming the previous value.

Comment: Alright, what value? Where will it get the value? Or are you looking to try to get it random?

Comment: the blanks are present when the value is the same as the previous value. in the example Joe has 3 items, but his name is only present in the first row. When his name is duplicated the cell in that row is left blank.

Comment: I believe those blanks are merged cells, and undoing that and filling it in can be problematic. I suggest either go to the source and get that to fill in those blanks, or use power query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the data is located in Sheet1, put this in cell A1 of Sheet2 :

```
=IF(ROW()=1,Sheet1!A1,IF(Sheet1!A1="",OFFSET(Sheet2!A1,-1,0),Sheet1!A1))
```

Then all the way down/rightwards. Done.

Idea :

- If the Sheet1 cell is not blank, take its value & put it in the same cell in Sheet2.
- If the Sheet1 cell is blank, take the value from the
- cell above in Sheet2. Except for 1st row.

Please share if it works/not.

Comment: How do you know the OP has 2 sheets?

Comment: I didn't know. I assume it. | If it is not, OP may just adjust the Sheet1 to his/her Sheet name in the formula accordingly.

Comment: Don't assume stuff. Confirm it. Confirm with the OP about that so you can make sure your assumption is correct.

Comment: pending OP response..